# Using razor syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is the code I have.  I basically want to look at my model and see if anything exists.  Using ternary operator to show or hide based on existence.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        (@Model.MyProperties.Any()) ? $('#removeall-toggle').show() : $('#removeall-toggle').hide();
    });
```

I'm getting an error in chrome dev tools that says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: False is not defined
```

How do i fix this, or is this a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: is the javascript in a script tag inside the same file as the Model you are referencing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Any()` method will return `True` and your code is going to produce the below javascript code when the page is rendered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    (True) ? $('#removeall-toggle').show() : $('#removeall-toggle').hide();
});
```

Now Javascript will think that `True` is variable and try to use it's value and it cannot find it as it is not defined earlier in your page. ***Since this variable is not defined earlier in your page, you are getting the  undefined error.***

undefined `True` varibale is not boolean `true` in javascript.  So do a string comparison.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    ("@Model.Products.Any()"==="True") ?
                        $('#removeall-toggle').show() : $('#removeall-toggle').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 4):

`@Model.MyProperties.Any()` produces a boolean, and when the boolean is output into javascript, you end up with "False" instead of "false". There are a couple of ways to address this.

#### Approach 1: JSON Serialize

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.MyProperties.Any())) ? $('#removeall-toggle').show() : $('#removeall-toggle').hide();
});
```

Or, a simpler version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var shouldShow = @JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.MyProperties.Any());
    $('#removeall-toggle').toggle(shouldShow);
});
```

#### Approach 2: Only output what you need

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    @if(Model.MyProperties.Any())
    {
       @:$('#removeall-toggle').show();
    }
    else
    {
       @:$('#removeall-toggle').hide();
    }
});
```